# get items counts in list c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a list of words and I want to count each word, then select top 1000 ordered by the number of word occurrence in descending. is there any fast way to conduct this task. thanks for all.

```
for (int j = 0; j < tokens.Length; j++)
{
  if (!yy.ContainsKey(tokens[j]))
                    yy.Add(tokens[j], 1);
                else
                    yy[tokens[j]]++;

 }
```

i want to change the dictionary with List.

Comment: What did you try ? Where is your code ?

Comment: But have you tried anything yet? Did you even google it?

Comment: Why do you keep calling `ToString`? What is the full type of `tokens`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<string> yourList = ... 

var top1000 = yourList.GroupBy(s => s).Select(g => new { Value = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
                      .OrderByDescending(p => p.Count).Take(1000);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using LINQ:

```
var query = words.GroupBy(word => word)
                 .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                 .Select(g => g.Key)
                 .Take(1000);
```